# Azure SQL to On-Premise SQL Server Data Transfer

Tags: sql-server, azure, database

I need to securely transfer data from a SQL Server in Microsoft Azure to a SQL Server on-premises. I have been researching different methods but I have not found the right way.

Following is the list of what I have considered.

1. [Encrypted SQL Server connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316898/how-to-enable-ssl-encryption-for-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-mi). How can I selectively enforce encryption on particular IP addresses? The source SQL Server services other clients that are not ready for enforced encryption.
2. [Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime). It looks like it is in alpha version and designed for full integration and not file sharing between independent parties.
3. SSH Tunnel. What is the best way to setup SSH server and client on Windows?
4. File transfer using SFTP. This method is inefficient and does not allow for real time access.
5. Other method that you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Azure Sync Group?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync